# Pyspark DDL SQL Query on different host

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to python and entire gluescript thing. I wanted to execute a delete query on a different DB server. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
def remove_from_db(driver, url, dbtable, user, password):
    query = "delete from abctable where end_date >='1-11-2023'"
    
    spark.write.format("jdbc") \
        .option("driver", driver) \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", dbtable) \
        .option("user", user) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("query", query) \
        .load()
```